# Mongo Schema for Quiz Site

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a small Node/Mongo app that serves users with up to 3 questions per day. Users can only answer yes or no and the correct answer will be determined at a later time (these questions are closer to predictions). Currently, I have these documents:

- User

  - id
- Question

  - id
- QuestionAnswer

  - id
  - question_id (ref)
- UserAnswer

  - id
  - question_id (ref)
  - user_id (ref)

What is the most efficient way to query the db so I get today's questions but also check whether that user has answered that question already? I feel like I'm overthinking it. I've tried a couple ways that seem to be overkill.

Comment: why are you making too much relations in NoSQL database you can add UserAnswer object into user and QuestionAnswer object into Question. and $push and $pull keyword make your query for Answering

Comment: Wouldn't adding the UserAnswer object into user create a large User object after some time? Each time a user submits an answer to a question, it will push it to the document.

Comment: that is the main benefit to use NoSQL, that you can get whole data by one query and save into your global variable and use it when it require to show, it will be fast as compare to query again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good to put them all in one schema since we don't have joins in mongodb.
It is faster than using relations.

Also for keeping your query small, take a look at [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/).

You should stay away from relations till you have a good reason for using them. So, what you need is only one schema.

Comment: So I should store every user who answers the question within that schema? So basically one Question document with user, user answer, and the real answer as fields. Does that still work once there are thousands of users answering every question?